# Graphically produce a undirected / unweighted graph

Tags: c, matlab, graph, undirected-graph, cayley

I am currently working on a project to to calculate the God's Number and Devils Algorithm of the `2x2` and `3x3` Rubiks Cube. I have successfully created the graphs using my own structure types in C, but would like to visually represent this like so:

[image]

Now the problem is that the `2x2` Cayley graph has around 3.5 million nodes and 18 million edges, significantly more for the `3x3`. I can easily produce an Adjacency Matrix from my program to use in an external package if that's necessary.

Is there a Library in C I can use? Would Matlab be able to create this for me? How do I go about a graph of such large amount of nodes?

Comment: have you tired [`gplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html)?

Comment: So it turns out there is no way to conveniently produce an adjacency matrix. It takes FAR too long and the file is FAR too big - more than 1TB by approximation.

Comment: are you sure your matrix is of type `sparse`?